# Filter gives negative values (SciPy filter)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signals

I have one problem with filtering my dataset (np array) with `scipy.signal.butter` (or ellip). My data has only positive values, but after filtering, there are negative values in the output array. The code and graphics are shown below. Question: **why do negative values appear and how can I fix it?** Thank you in advance!

Load the data:

```
 data_s = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python and programming/Jupyter/Filter/320_Hz.dat', header=None, squeeze=True)
    data = data_s.values
    #"turn over" the negative parts
    for i in range(len(data)): 
        if data[i] < 0:
            data[i] = abs(data[i]) * 2
```

Filt:

```
F_rate = 320.0
sample_time = 1 / F_rate

low = 79.9
high = 80.1
low_d = low / (0.5 * F_rate)
high_d = high / (0.5 * F_rate)

Wn = [low_d,high_d] 
#b, a = signal.ellip(4, 3, 40, Wn, 'bandpass', analog=False) 
b,a = signal.butter(6, Wn, 'bandpass', analog=False)

output = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data) 
print(output)
plt.magnitude_spectrum(output, Fs=F_rate)
```

Out:

```
[  7.93572645e-12   1.82355646e-12  -8.99759647e-11 ...,  -5.01622276e+03
   1.18142432e+04   4.98038137e+03]
```

Spectrum of output data:

[image]

Input data:

[image]

Output data (negative values):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do negative values appear

Filtering can, in general, produce values outside of the input range. In particular, filtering the data with a band-pass removes low frequency components. The most low frequency component one can imagine is the mean, which is completely removed. In other words: **a band-pass filter centers the data at zero**. This is only possible if the data contains both of positive and negative values.

> how can I fix it?

This one is tricky. To tell how to "fix" it one would need to *why the data is filtered* and *why the output should be only positive*. There is not really anything to fix, because the filter is doing exactly what it is suppodes to do.

These are some of the available options:

- Fix your expectations and accept that you get negative values.
- Maybe you do not need a band-pass? Use a high-pass filter that only removes high frequencies but does not touch low frequencies.
- Add `np.min(output)` or some other offset to the output
- Apply the same transform to the output that was used on the input: `if data[i] < 0: data[i] = abs(data[i]) * 2` (although this feels like a very strange thing to do from my signal processing perspective)